# Show alertDialog and logout after a specific ammount of time from anywhere in the app

Tags: android, timer, android-alertdialog

After one hour from logging into the app I would like to show an Alert that warns the user that his session will expire and five minutes after that I want to log him out. The user may be in any acivity of the app. What is the best approach for this without the activity, that he is currently in, being an issue.

What I have already done is set a countDownTimer right after he logs in and use the onTick and onFinsh methods to handle these events and I use a Toast to show the message. I don't think that this is the best practice. Do you have any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this start a **service** as your user login and then keep a **counter** on until the specified time is reached then show a **notification** in system tray clicking on that will start a pending **intent** where you can implement the rest of the logout logic also.
here is a simple example of creating a notification

```
    // Instantiate a Builder object.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
// Creates an Intent for the Activity
Intent notifyIntent =
        new Intent(new ComponentName(this, ResultActivity.class));
// Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
// Creates the PendingIntent
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        notifyIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

// Puts the PendingIntent into the notification builder
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
// Notifications are issued by sending them to the
// NotificationManager system service.
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds an anonymous Notification object from the builder, and
// passes it to the NotificationManager
mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html) about the notifications

or you can create a floating window with special **permission** request. which you have to get from the system otherwise you won't be able to create the **floating window** also called **overlays**.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256) is a full tutorial on that but this approach is not recommended so I would suggest you go with notification.